# make tornadofx combo box handle keypress to select item

Tags: javafx, kotlin, tornadofx

On a lot of platforms, if I start typing "a" when the combo box below has the focus, it will automatically highlight "alice". Is it possible to get that behavior with Tornadofx/Javafx? I tried adding `setEditable(true)` but that just allows me to freeform edit the name and it doesn't do any highlighting/selection of the existing names.

```
class MainView : View("Hello TornadoFX") {
    val names = FXCollections.observableArrayList(
        "alice", "bob", "charlie", "denise")

    override val root = vbox {
        combobox<String> {
            items = names
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the TornadoFX `makeAutocompletable()` extension for that. Here is an example with a bit tighter syntax as well. Note that normally you'd bind the result of the combobox to an observable string property, so the builder syntax would be `combobox(name, names)` or something like that.

```
class MainView : View("Hello TornadoFX") {
    val names = observableListOf("alice", "bob", "charlie", "denise")

    override val root = vbox {
        combobox(values = names) {
            makeAutocompletable()
        }
    }
}
```

You can also pass a filter function to `makeAutocompletable` if you need to change the filter criteria.